# Decoding the below Scala code

Tags: scala, scala-collections

While reading a book on Scala i stumbled upon the following code. Am unable to segregate the code into the function, parameters, variables.

```
 val feeds = Map("Andy Hunt"   -> "blog.toolshed.com",  
                "Dave Thomas" -> "pragdave.me",     
                "NFJS"        -> "nofluffjuststuff.com/blog")

val fiterName = feeds filter { element =>   
  val (key, value) = element    
  (key startsWith "D") && (value contains "pragprog")   
}
```

Can some one explain me the code step by step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`feeds` is a `Map[String, String]` which maps a person to a blog.

Then that map is iterates with a `filter`, which attempts to filter any author which starts with the capital letter `D` and his value contains the word "pragprog".

When you `filter` on a `Map`, you get a tuple which has the key as the first element and the value as the second element. Using round brackets, it looks like this:

```
val filterName = feeds.filter(element => {
   val (key, value) = element    
   key.startsWith("D") && value.contains("pragprog")
})
```

Note that filter by itself is a [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), it takes another function as input. This function takes an argument of type `A`, which in our case is a tuple `(String, String)`, and produces a boolean which indicates if the element matches the condition or not. Inside the filter, they used tuple deconstruction:

```
val (key, value) = element
```

Which takes a `Tuple2[String, String]` and calls it's `unapply` method, allowing you to access the components of the tuple by name, and not via `._1` and `_.2`

Comment: Well i understood that looking at the code but what am wondering is? As per the spec filter takes a predicate (String,String)=>Boolean. With that in mind what does val (key,value) = element mean? then on what value the boolean expression (key startsWith "D") && (value contains "pragprog") is invoked?

Comment: @Gurupraveen Updated the answer to reflect your question.

Comment: One more question, what if i don't want to use tuple deconstruction? how would i achieve same results?

Comment: @Gurupraveen `element._1.startsWith("D") && element._2.contains("pragprog")`